# What is template<> inline bla bla

Tags: c++, c++11

I stumbled across the following:

```
template<> inline bool Value::GetValue<bool>() const {
    return m_Value.ValueBoolean();   // union
}
```

Can’t understand what the empty template declaration does ?

Comment: It's a [template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization).

Comment: [Template Specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization).

Comment: Good question (hard to search if you don't know the terms), but most likely a duplicate.

Comment: "template<> inline bla bla" add another bla and I think you almost have a *NSYNC song. Always wondered why they were dereferencing a constant.

Comment: Which C++ book are you using to learn the language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an [explicit specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization).

Answer (score 3):

This is an *explicit specialization* of a template function for type `bool`. Explicit specialization is where `template <>` syntax is used.

```
template <typename T> void foo(T t) // Main template
{ 
  ... 
} 

template <> void foo<bool>(bool b) // Explicit specialization for type `bool`
{ 
  ... 
}
```

The fact that in your example it is applied to a template of a *class member function* is completely inconsequential. The fact that the function is declared `inline` is also completely besides the point.

Comment: Note that the return types don't have to be the same or even related.